# How can I troubleshoot Apache timeouts on Windows 2008?

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm running sites on a Windows 2008 server, some of which are running on IIS and some on Apache (WAMP). Every few hours, my apache sites timeout, and I can only get them back through restarting Apache. How can I troubleshoot this? I should also mention that these troubles only started a few days ago after moving servers.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: also, my Apache error log shows no entries for the time when the timeout was occuring.

Comment: did you take a look through apache error log??

Comment: Just edited my reply to say that the error log doesnt show anything :-)

Comment: can you enable reqtimeout_module in apache and see if error log has anything new. Or any (general) new output might come along??!

Comment: enabled, error log didnt show anything new.

Comment: do you have many requests on the apache server??

Comment: which apache version are you running, and have you tried to uninstall it and then re-install it again?

Comment: 2.4.2. I haven't tried reinstalling. Can that really help?

Comment: might help, yes. as I can see at least.